# Scrollable View Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm currently redoing from the start a school project which is basically a view with a label in it.

Right now all I want to do is showing some text in the label and making the view scrollable if the text is too long. I manage to make the view scrollable by giving a size to the label, but if the text is to long the scroll bar wont help see it entirely.

This is the code I have so far (it's just the createPartControl function, tell me if you need more):

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

ScrolledComposite sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);

aLabel = new Label(sc, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
aLabel.setBackground(getSite().getShell().getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
aLabel.setSize(400,400);

sc.setContent(aLabel);
sc.setMinSize(aLabel.computeSize(aLabel.getBounds().width, aLabel.getBounds().height));
sc.setExpandVertical(true);
sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create label with `SWT.WRAP` style constant, instead of `SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick and I don't even need the scroll anymore.